# MongoDB MapReduce key as a document

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Is it possible in MongoDB MapReduce to emit keys that are documents themselves? Something like

`emit({type: 1, date: ...}, 12);`

When I do this MapReduce completes with success but in my reduced results I also see emitted values so I am wondering what's wrong.

Comment: maybe if you include example of unexpected results you see I can expand the answer to explain what you are seeing.  I have no idea what "I see emitted values" means so it's hard to address that part of it.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use document as emit key**.  The reduce function combines documents with the same key into one document. If the map function emits a single document for a particular key, the reduce function will not be called. 

Can you share your code in snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use a document for key and/or value.  It will work exactly the same as when they are primitive types.